# What is the best way to measure time series similarity with these features?

Tags: time-series, unevenly-spaced-time-series

I have a time series data from a wearable device. I have two time series as arrays df1.VALUE1 and  df2.VALUE1. I would like to to measure similarity of these arrays. These arrays have different sampling rates and different array lengths. For both arrays measurements happens in different intervals, usually around 15-30 minutes. Also, measurement start and end times are different for each array. How to measure similarity of these two arrays?

I tried using DTW, but warping plot shows me that it aligned both time series on top of each other.I am not sure hoe to interpret that. Does that mean it aligns time series so that they start and end at the same time?